# Simple LINQ select (using Entity Framework) does not return values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am new at C# and Entity Framework. My LINQ select never returns a value from my Entity Editor. I have a table called **Editor** with this data:

```
Editor
---------------------------------
Id |  Name    | Email 
1  |  Oreilly | oreilly@email.com
2  |  Apress  | apress@email.com
3  |  Abril   | abril@email.com
4  |  Europa  | europa@email.com
```

The *connection string* on my **Web.Config** is:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EditoraContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=livraria;
         uid=sa;pwd=sa;Trusted_Connection=true;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

In the folder **Models** in my project I have class **Editora** as below:

```
 namespace LivrariaVirtual.Models
{
    public class Editora
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Livro> Livros { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I have a class **LivrariaVirtualContext** to keep the diferent *DbContexts*:

```
namespace LivrariaVirtual.Models
{
    public class LivrariaVirtualContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Editora> Editoras { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Livro> Livros { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a class named **EditoraRepository** that has a method **FetchAll** that should return all records from the table **Editoras**:

```
namespace LivrariaVirtual.Models
{
    public class EditoraRepository
    {

        private LivrariaVirtualContext context = new LivrariaVirtualContext();

        public List<Editora> FetchAll()
        {
            var consulta = from e in context.Editoras
                           select e;            
            return consulta.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I use this method **FetchAll** on my controller, but it doesn't return anything.  Here is my controller **EditorasController**:

```
namespace LivrariaVirtual.Controllers
{
    public class EditorasController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Editoras/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var editoraRepository = new EditoraRepository();                                    
            return View(editoraRepository.FetchAll());
        }

    }
}
```

I have tried to debug using a variable called **test** using a break point.

```
namespace LivrariaVirtual.Controllers
{
    public class EditorasController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Editoras/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var editoraRepository = new EditoraRepository();
            var teste = editoraRepository.FetchAll();
            return View(editoraRepository.FetchAll());
        }

    }
}
```

The value of *test* is: **Count = 0**.

Can somebody help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is with the name of your DBContext class and the name of your connectionstring.

The default convention is for the DBContext class to match the connectionstring. In your case, the `DBContext` class name is `LivrariaVirtualContext` but your connectionstring name is `EditoraContext`.

If you wanted to keep the connectionstring name, you do have the option of passing the name of the connectionstring when instantiating `LivrarVirtualContext`

Example:

```
private LivrariaVirtualContext context = new LivrariaVirtualContext("EditoraContext");
```

Comment: I think you're right. This would also mean that somewhere an auto-generated empty database is lying around having a name like "LivrariaVirtual.Models.LivrariaVirtualContext".

Comment: I changed the connection string to LivrariaVirtualContext and now everything works perfectly.  Thank you, Ganesh!